# How to debug uncaught (in promise): EmptyError: no elements in sequence caused by router.navigate?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm trying to implement a simple angular route

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
   { path: ''        ,redirectTo: '/recipes', pathMatch: 'full'},
   { path: 'recipes'              , component: RecipesComponent},
   { path: 'recipes/:recipeName'  , component: RecipesComponent},
];
```

in some component that generates the list, i have a function that on click of a 
updates state variable and routes, though I also have fetching mechanism subscriber happening on initialization.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .subscribe(
        (params: {Params}) => {

          this.selectedRecipe = this.findRecipeByName(params['recipeName']);  
        });
  }


   navRecipe(recipeName: string): void {
      let path = '/recipes/' + recipeName;
      this.selectedRecipe = this.findRecipeByName(recipeName);
      this.router.navigate([path]);
   }
```

But when I try to click on a link that reroutes to component with parameter I get the following:

```
core.js:1350 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): EmptyError: no elements in sequence
EmptyError: no elements in sequence
    at new EmptyError (EmptyError.js:28)
    at FirstSubscriber._complete (first.js:154)
    at FirstSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (Subscriber.js:122)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._complete (mergeMap.js:150)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (Subscriber.js:122)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._complete (Subscriber.js:140)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (Subscriber.js:122)
    at EmptyObservable._subscribe (EmptyObservable.js:83)
    at EmptyObservable.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:172)
    at EmptyObservable.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:160)
    at new EmptyError (EmptyError.js:28)
    at FirstSubscriber._complete (first.js:154)
    at FirstSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (Subscriber.js:122)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._complete (mergeMap.js:150)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (Subscriber.js:122)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._complete (Subscriber.js:140)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (Subscriber.js:122)
    at EmptyObservable._subscribe (EmptyObservable.js:83)
    at EmptyObservable.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:172)
    at EmptyObservable.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:160)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:824)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
    at eval (zone.js:873)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4621)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:602)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:503)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I encountered the same error with Angular v 4.4.6. There were two alternative solutions I found to resolve the error. One was adding `pathMatch: 'full'` to every route definition. The other was downgrading rxjs below v5.5.3. If one does not work for you perhaps the other will.

**update:** it appears the problem has been fixed in rxjs v5.5.5. In a project using Angular 5.0.5, after upgrading rxjs to v5.5.5 the error stopped happening.

Comment: This works for me. Thank you Evan, thank you for posting!!

Comment: Thanks..changed "rxjs": "^5.1.0" to "rxjs": "5.5.2" working now

Answer (score 14):

Angular latest version bug. Add `pathMatch: 'full'` to all routes.

```
 {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
   path: 'about',
   component: AboutComponent,
   pathMatch: 'full'
  },
```

Comment: Could you add a version number and source?

Comment: I only had one route failing - so I tried just adding , pathMatch: 'full' to that route only - didn't work.  Really do need to add it to every route.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error with Angular 5.0.1 and rxjs 5.5.3. We did not encounter the exception when we changed the order in the routes array. So for your example:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '',                    redirectTo: '/recipes', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'recipes/:recipeName', component: RecipesComponent},
    { path: 'recipes',             component: RecipesComponent},
];
```

Putting the more detailed path (`recipes/:recipeName`) before the general path (`recipes`).